# How to hook watchdog script for existence of a WP page?

Tags: hooks

I would like to have a watchdog script which checks the (un)availability of a certain DB entry, namely a certain WP page.

The script itself is absolutely independent from WP and not difficult, but I don't know how where I hook this script into WP. 
It should be called with every website visit.

Comment: how do you define a visit, every page view? what is supposed to happen if it does or does not exist?

Comment: Yes, every page view. There is very limited traffic, this is ok.   The script will send a email that I immediately be aware when there's an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to create a simple [Must Use Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and check for your page in a function hooked to an [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), like `wp_loaded`

```
function wpd_check_page_exists(){
    $page = get_page_by_title( 'The Page' );
    if( !$page ){
        wp_mail( 'you@example.com', 'a message from your site', 'the page is gone!' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpd_check_page_exists' );
```

You may want to use a different function to query the page, depending on how you identify whether it exists or not, like [`get_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) if you want to pass an ID, or [`get_page_by_path`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path), or [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).